# Cambiar el color de un chart js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

tengo un grafico que deseo poder cambiar a color blaco, ya que el fondo debo ponerle un color oscuro, pero no se y he buscado pero no encuentro realmente como cambiar el color del grafico, quisiera saber si es posible y que deberia hacer para esto.

He probado con style="background-color: white;" pero parece que no hace nada.

Adjunto mi grafico:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo del grafico:

```
var lineData = {
                labels: label,
                datasets: [{
                    label: "Peso",
                    backgroundColor: '#a7281a',
                    borderColor: "#a7281a",
                    pointBackgroundColor: "#a7281a",
                    pointBorderColor: "#fff",
                    data: data,
                }, ]
            };

            var lineOptions = {
                responsive: true,
                animation: {
                    onComplete: function(){
                        var ctx = this.chart.ctx;
                        ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily, 'normal', Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
                        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
                        ctx.textAlign = 'center';
                        ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';

                        this.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset){
                            for(var i = 0; i < dataset.data.length; i++){
                                for(var key in dataset._meta){
                                    var model = dataset._meta[key].data[i]._model;
                                    ctx.fillText(dataset.data[i], model.x, model.y - 5);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            };

            ctx = document.getElementById("lineChart").getContext("2d");
            myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'line',
                data: lineData,
                options: lineOptions,
            });
```

Gracias de ante mano :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> tengo un grafico que deseo poder cambiar a color blaco, ya que el fondo debo ponerle un color oscuro.

Lo que sucede con `style="background-color: white;"` es que es una propiedad de CSS, la cual entra en conflicto con la librería de [chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/).

Siempre que se pueda es recomendable trabajar todo desde `Javascript`.
Para cambiar el color de los `datasets` a blanco solo tienes que modificar las propiedades de:

```
backgroundColor: '#ffffff73', // Fondo del gráfico
borderColor: "#f1f0f0", // Lineas que bordean el gráfico
pointBackgroundColor: "#cfcfcf", // Punto del gráfico
pointBorderColor: "#fff", // Circunferencia que bordean el punto del gráfico
```

En cuanto al fondo detrás del gráfico si iniciaste en usar CSS puedes insertar tu `style` de la siguiente forma:

```
<canvas id="lineChart" width="400" height="400" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.500)"></canvas>
```

Establecí un blanco con una pequeña transparencia.

Esto funcionara pero tiene un inconveniente y es que nos tapara los números (valores) y los nombres (pesos) de nuestro gráfico. 

Para solventar esto necesitamos modificar los parámetros de `lineOptions` del siguiente modo.

```js
var lineData = {
  labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
  datasets: [{
      label: "Peso",
      backgroundColor: '#ffffff73', // Fondo del gráfico
      borderColor: "#f1f0f0", // Lineas que bordean el gráfico
      pointBackgroundColor: "#cfcfcf", // Punto del gráfico
      pointBorderColor: "#fff", // Circunferencia que bordean el punto del gráfico         
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
  }, ],
};

var lineOptions = {
  responsive: true,
  animation: {
      onComplete: function(){
          var ctx = this.chart.ctx;
          ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily, 'normal', Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
          ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
          ctx.textAlign = 'center';
          ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';

          this.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset){
              for(var i = 0; i < dataset.data.length; i++){
                  for(var key in dataset._meta){
                      var model = dataset._meta[key].data[i]._model;
                      ctx.fillText(dataset.data[i], model.x, model.y - 5);
                  }
              }
          });
      }
  },
  legend: {
    labels: {
        fontColor: "#fff",
        fontSize: 13
    }
},
  scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        time: {
          unit: 'date'
        },
        gridLines: {
          display: false,
          drawBorder: false
        },
        ticks: {
          fontColor : "#fff",
          maxTicksLimit: 7
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
          fontColor : "#fff",
            maxTicksLimit: 5,
            padding: 10,
          },
          gridLines: {
            color: "rgb(234, 236, 244)",
            zeroLineColor: "rgb(234, 236, 244)",
            drawBorder: false,
            borderDash: [2],
            zeroLineBorderDash: [2]
          }
        }],
  }
},









ctx = document.getElementById("lineChart").getContext("2d");
myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: lineData,
  options: lineOptions,
});
```

```html
<canvas id="lineChart" width="400" height="400" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.500)"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.3/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
```

Establecí lineas detrás del fondo que siguen el recorrido del valor para que el usuario pueda entender con mayor facilidad del gráfico.
Se puede modificar el color o eliminarlo, solo busque `gridLines`

**Actualización**

Si deseas cambiar el color de los ejes lo puedes lograr modificando los parámetros de `xAxes` y `yAxes` luego edita `fontColor`; de igual forma puedes cambiar el color de los valores encima del gráfico en el aparatado `ctx.fillStyle`   
Por ejemplo un color amarillo en los ejes y un color naranja en los valores encima del gráfico.

```js
var lineData = {
  labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
  datasets: [{
      label: "Peso",
      backgroundColor: '#ffffff73', // Fondo del gráfico
      borderColor: "#f1f0f0", // Lineas que bordean el gráfico
      pointBackgroundColor: "#cfcfcf", // Punto del gráfico
      pointBorderColor: "#fff", // Circunferencia que bordean el punto del gráfico         
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
  }, ],
};

var lineOptions = {
  responsive: true,
  animation: {
      onComplete: function(){
          var ctx = this.chart.ctx;
          ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily, 'normal', Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
          ctx.fillStyle = 'orange'; //Color del valor encima del gráfico 
          ctx.textAlign = 'center';
          ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';

          this.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset){
              for(var i = 0; i < dataset.data.length; i++){
                  for(var key in dataset._meta){
                      var model = dataset._meta[key].data[i]._model;
                      ctx.fillText(dataset.data[i], model.x, model.y - 5);
                  }
              }
          });
      }
  },
  legend: {
    labels: {
        fontColor: "#fff",
        fontSize: 13
    }
},
  scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        time: {
          unit: 'date'
        },
        gridLines: {
          display: false,
          drawBorder: false
        },
        ticks: {
          fontColor : "#ffff00", //Color eje X
          maxTicksLimit: 7
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
          fontColor : "#ffff00", //Color eje Y
            maxTicksLimit: 5,
            padding: 10,
          },
          gridLines: {
            color: "rgb(234, 236, 244)",
            zeroLineColor: "rgb(234, 236, 244)",
            drawBorder: false,
            borderDash: [2],
            zeroLineBorderDash: [2]
          }
        }],
  }
},









ctx = document.getElementById("lineChart").getContext("2d");
myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: lineData,
  options: lineOptions,
});
```

```html
<canvas id="lineChart" width="400" height="400" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.500)"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.3/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Veo que esto funciona...pero..igual sigo con mi duda, si por ejemplo quiero cambiar el color de los valores del eje izquierdo y el eje bajo, como haria eso, es lo que mas necesito :( son los que tienen los valores, y las fechas

Comment: Eso es fácil, para lograrlo solo debes modificar el aparatados de los ejes. busca xAxes y yAxes, luego fontColor en ambos, veras que tienen un color hexadecimal #fff tan solo cámbialo por el color que necesites. Ej: el amarillo es: #ffff00

Comment: Actualizo la publicación para explicarme mejor, échale un vistazo

Comment: Gracias ya funciono :)

Answer (score 0):

Para cambiar el color del gráfico lo puedes hacer sobre `backgroundColor` de la variable `lineData`, y para cambiar el color del `canvas` por `css`.

```js
var lineData = {
                labels: [1,2,3,4,5],
                datasets: [{
                    label: "Peso",
                    backgroundColor: '#fff',
                    borderColor: "#a7281a",
                    pointBackgroundColor: "#a7281a",
                    pointBorderColor: "#fff",
                    data: [100,200,150,300,50],
                }, ]
            };

            var lineOptions = {
                responsive: true,
                animation: {
                    onComplete: function(){
                        var ctx = this.chart.ctx;
                        ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily, 'normal', Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
                        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
                        ctx.textAlign = 'center';
                        ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';

                        this.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset){
                            for(var i = 0; i < dataset.data.length; i++){
                                for(var key in dataset._meta){
                                    var model = dataset._meta[key].data[i]._model;
                                    ctx.fillText(dataset.data[i], model.x, model.y - 5);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            };

            ctx = document.getElementById("lineChart").getContext("2d");
            myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'line',
                data: lineData,
                options: lineOptions,
            });
```

```css
canvas#lineChart {
  background-color: #444;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
<canvas id="lineChart" style="display: block; width: 392px; height: 256px;" width="392" height="256" class="chartjs-render-monitor"></canvas>
```